# I am trying to retrieve data from my firebase but somehow the timestamp is being recieved in java.util.data format

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.photoblog, PID: 23142 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method com.example.photoblog.BlogPost.setTimestamp argument 1 has type java.sql.Timestamp, got java.util.Date . . . . . . . . at com.example.photoblog.HomeFragment$1.onEvent(**HomeFragment**.java:60) at com.example.photoblog.HomeFragment$1.onEvent(**HomeFragment**.java:52)

This is my code

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
private RecyclerView blog_view;
private List<BlogPost> blog_list;
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
private Adapter adapter;
public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    blog_list=new ArrayList<>();
    blog_view=view.findViewById(R.id.blog_view);
    firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    adapter=new Adapter(blog_list);
    blog_view.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    blog_view.setAdapter(adapter);

    firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            for(DocumentChange doc: queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())
            {
                if(doc.getType()==DocumentChange.Type.ADDED)
                {
                    BlogPost blogPost=doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class);
                    blog_list.add(blogPost);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Please see [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you added the field data type to timestamp in firebase you can only fetch the same in the code with the same data type but if you want that value to be converted to string just cast the value to string.

Comment: public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

Comment: I am using the same data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Object Class you must be importing the wrong Timestamp.

Check your imports. It has to be `com.google.firebase.Timestamp`